# Остаток от деления -12 на 5

Tags: python, математика

Встретился с такой интересной ситуацией при вычислении -12%5 на разных языках.
На python:

```
-12%5
3
```

На java:

```
-12%5
-2
```

На JavaScript:

```
-12%5
-2
```

Почему python так вычисляет?

Comment: Посмотрите: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883004/the-modulo-operation-on-negative-numbers-in-python

Comment: Вопрос должен быть почему ява и яваскрипт так вычисляют. Питон вычисляет правильно.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Деление_с_остатком#В_программировании

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Марк Лутц, писал следующее:
"Существует один очень тонкий момент: оператор // обычно называют оператором деления с усечением, но более точно было бы называть его оператором деления с округлением результата вниз – он округляет результат до ближайшего меньшего целого значения, то есть до целого числа, расположенного ниже истинного результата."